# Proper way to run a PyCharm project

Tags: python, cron

This is a seemingly simple problem but it proves to be harder than expected.

I've created a project in pycharm in the following layout

```
bin
    main
helpers
    userhelper
models
    user
    session
tests
    userTest
```

in my main I run the code that calls everything and this works like a charm in pycharm. Now I want to run this on a server and start it with cron. How do I start this from cron while keeping all the module references in place?

I guess I need to add the root of my project to the python path. To do this I added the following bash script to invoke my project with:

```
PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/steven/projectX"
export PYTHONPATH
python bin/main.py
```

But this does not seem to do anything, what would be the best way to periodically run the bin/main.py within this project and have all my modules and things like 'ConfigParser.RawConfigParser().read(os.path.abspath("../configuration.cfg"))' in place relative to my project?

EDIT: I am not trying to fix my imports or debugging my code, I have a large project in pycharm that runs a simulation that I want to invoke on the server an maintain within my development setup. The question is how do I run this in the same way pycharm does?

Comment: What does 'does not seem to do anything' mean? How did you run this? From where? What happened? What did you check for?

Comment: the invoke script is in the project root, and the error is that the modules are missing, it seems my pythonpath is still incorrect

Comment: When you run it from cron or when you run it on the command line? Please update your question with the relevant info.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're interested in making a distributable Python package.  You should read through the tutorial [here](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distributing/).  Ultimately, you're going to want to write a setup.py (sure you could call it something else, but it's like renaming `self` -- why do it?) that will configure your project.  Now a word of advice since I've seen many people go down a wrong path here.  You NEVER want to modify your PYTHONPATH directly.  It might be the quickest solution to get something up and working, but it WILL cause lasting problems.

Comment: Thanks, this is the direction I'm looking for, however I am not completely sure if this is the best way to have a maintainable project for both development and production.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on that?  I think that's sort of the point of making a distributable package.

Comment: Well, the thing is that this is meant to only have one instance, it should not be run anywhere else, just on that server. There is some overhead when creating a distributable package that does not contribute to the goal of this project. I'll have another look.

Answer (score 0):

So I've found the way of dealing with mu issue here. The best option would obviously be to create a distributable python package and use this. However since I am developing a simulation that has loads of features and desired outcomes there is a lot of tuning going on and having to create a package every time I want to run the project is a bit out of the scope for my project.
What I do want to do is being able to run the files in a similar way to how I am doing this on my development machine with PyCharm. The way I resolved this is to have my main.py in the root of my project and to have all references relative to the executed file. This means my userhelper looks for the datastore as follows:

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
                    "resources/" + settings['datastore_filename']
```

This resolves my issue of not being able to run my project on the server the same way it runs on my PC.